# Wrong results after method invocation

Tags: java, user-input

So I am taking a Java course right now and the assignment is to call certain methods from the main method, and have them execute, then pass along their output to the main method. Everything works fine, except that for some reason the user inputs are not being updated. I have two separate classes that ask for a user input, and if the user input is below zero, they have to reenter a number before zero before they proceed. Even though they enter multiple numbers, and the numbers are above zero so it returns the value, it only ever returns the first input they ever made, not the correct one. Any insight on this guys? First time asking a question here, so I really don't know if I broke any formatting or whatnot. Any help is appreciated.

The code I'm posting is not my actual code for the class, its just a separate program I made that demonstrates the problem, and can be used to fix my primary code. It's just cut down on a lot of the useless stuff.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class tezsters {

    public static double test(double test1) {
        Scanner scanner=new Scanner(System.in);

        while(test1<=0) {
            System.out.println("Test one must be above zero, please reenter");
            test1 = Double.parseDouble(scanner.nextLine());
            System.out.println(test1);// this line is just here to test if the user input was being assigned to test1, which it was.
            if(test1>0) {
                return test1;
            }
        }
        return test1;
    }


    public static double tests(double test2) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (test2 <= 0) {
            System.out.println("Test two must be above zero, please reenter");
            test2 = Double.parseDouble(scanner.nextLine());
            System.out.println(test2);
            if (test2 > 0) {
                return test2;
            }
        }
        return test2;
    }


    public static double display(double test1, double test2){
        System.out.println("if test 1 is " + test1);
        System.out.println("Then test 2 is " + test2);
        return test1;
    }


    public static void main (String [] args) {

        Scanner scanner=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter test 1 value");
        double test1 = Double.parseDouble(scanner.nextLine());
        test(test1);
        System.out.println("Enter test 2 value");
        double test2 = Double.parseDouble(scanner.nextLine());
        tests(test2);
        display(test1,test2);

    }
}
```

Comment: Didn't read the whole thing yet, but you probably don't want to allocate more than one Scanner for System.in.  Allocate once, then set as static/instance field or pass in via method parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your main method you do the following:

```
double test1 = Double.parseDouble(scanner.nextLine());
test(test1);
System.out.println("Enter test 2 value");
double test2 = Double.parseDouble(scanner.nextLine());
tests(test2);
display(test1,test2);
```

So basically you create two doubles that you then pass in the `test` and `tests` methods. These numbers are then checked within the context of those method and if found to be negative you prompt the user to re-enter a number.

Problem is that finally, when you call the `display` method you never actually pass in the value returned by either `test` or `tests` but instead you pass in the original `test1` and `test2` hence why the final output will show only the user's original number input. Since both those methods return a double, you can store their return value to a variable and pass those in to `display`

In that sense your code should look like:

```
Scanner scanner=new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter test 1 value");
// initial value is created and passed in to test method here
double test1 = Double.parseDouble(scanner.nextLine());
// here we grab the return value of the test method
double value1 = test(test1);
System.out.println("Enter test 2 value");
// initial value is created and passed in to tests method here
double test2 = Double.parseDouble(scanner.nextLine());
// here we grab the return value of the tests method.
double value2 = tests(test2);
// pass in the value returned from both methods (ensuring we have the latest user input) to display
display(value1, value2);
```

Comment: I find this statement to be a bit confusing - "Since both those methods return a double, you can store their return value to a variable and pass those in to display". You can store the return value as long as the return type is non-void, not just when the return value is a double. Maybe you meant that the value could be stored in existing variables?

Comment: I don't think it's confusing at all. Since his methods are returning double he can store their return values in some variables and pass them on to display. What is confusing to you?

Comment: Could you elaborate more on the changes that need to be done? I did the changes that I perceived that you wanted me to make, and I still have the same issue of it returning only the initial value, even though the value of test1 and test2 are still being updated within their respective methods.

Comment: Honestly I didnt completly understand what you meant by your first response, so what I did is that in the method "test" under the if statement I made a new double called fin1 that was equal to the result of test1, and returned that to the main method. The same was done for the method tests and test 2. In the main method i just called for it to display fin1 and fin2 instead of test1 and test2.

Comment: I just went ahead and posted a sample of the changes you need to make. Please go ahead and check it.

Comment: Thanks alot man! It works fine now. You just saved me another 4 or so more hours of banging my head against a wall.

Comment: No problem at all. One thing you need to notice is that you need to study your code a bit better when having any issues. I understand that you're still learning but re-reading your code over and over when having issues is the first starting point in troubleshooting.

I also hope you understood why it was not working for you in the first place.

Comment: Also there is no need to answer this for youself :P. Just go ahead and have the answer I provided marked as accepted.